# REST ASSURED (JAVA): Extract value form response using jsonpath and validate with excel input value

Tags: java, rest-assured

Java code to compare response using the JsonPath with Excel input value. Using the JSONPath we should be able to validate the response

```
public void getAirportDetailswithcity(String eLongitude,String eLaititude,String eCity)
{
  //1. define the base url
  //http://restapi.demoqa.com/utilities/weather/city
  RestAssured.baseURI = prop.getProperty("serviceurl1");

  //2. define the http request:
  RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given()
                                        .filter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())
                                        .filter(new RequestLoggingFilter());

  JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
  requestParams.put("longitude", eLongitude);
  requestParams.put("latitude", eLaititude);
  requestParams.put("city", eCity);

  httpRequest.headers("Content-Type", "application/json");
  httpRequest.body(requestParams.toJSONString());

  //httpRequest.queryParam("city", "Mumbai");
  //3. make a request/execute the request:
  Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET);

  //System.out.println("Response Time : " + response.getTime());
  System.out.println("Response Time : " +response.getTimeIn(TimeUnit.SECONDS));


  //4. get the response body:
  String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
  System.out.println("Response Body is: "+ responseBody);
  logger.info("Response Body==>"+responseBody);
  //validate city name or validate the key or value
  Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains(eCity), true);
  System.out.println("City is: "+ eCity);

  //5. get the status code and validate it:
  int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
  System.out.println("the status code is: "+ statusCode);

  Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, TestUtil.RESPONSE_CODE_200);

  System.out.println("the status line is: "+ response.getStatusLine());


  //6. get the headers:
  Headers headers = response.getHeaders();
  System.out.println(headers);

  String contentType = response.getHeader("Content-Type");
  System.out.println("the value of content-type header is: "+ contentType);

  String contentLength = response.getHeader("Content-Length");
  System.out.println("the value of Content-Length header is: "+ contentLength);

  //String restime = response.getTimeIn("Seconds");

  //get the key value by using JsonPath:

  //Comment
  JsonPath jsonPathValue = response.jsonPath();
  //jsonPathValue.prettyPrint();


  String longitudeVal = jsonPathValue.get("longitude");
  //String longitudeVal = jsonPathValue.getString("data.longitude");

  System.out.println("the value of Longitude is: "+ longitudeVal);
  Assert.assertEquals(longitudeVal,eLongitude);

  Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains("longitude"), true);
  System.out.println("Longitude is: "+ eLongitude);

  Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains("latitude"), true);
  System.out.println("Laititude is: "+ eLaititude);
}
```

The JSON response in Postman looks like this
{
    "response": {
        "code": 200,
        "status": "success",
        "alert": [
            {
                "message": "Success",
                "type": "success",
                "skippable": 1
            }
        ],
        "from_cache": 0,
        "is_data": 1
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 6004,
            "airport_name": "Adampur Airport",
            "city": "Adampur",
            "country": "India",
            "iata": "AIP",
            "icao": "VIAX",
            "latitude": "31.4338",
            "longitude": "75.758797",
            "altitude": "775"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: JsonPath jsonPathValue = response.jsonPath();
  //jsonPathValue.prettyPrint();


  String longitudeVal = jsonPathValue.get("longitude");
  //String longitudeVal = jsonPathValue.getString("data.longitude");

  System.out.println("the value of Longitude is: "+ longitudeVal);
  Assert.assertEquals(longitudeVal,eLongitude);   we should be able to validate the value of Longitude from excel and Json response whether both matches

Comment: Please format correctly. Can't read. Also what is your question? What are you trying  to do? What is the issue you are facing? Is there an error trace? What have you done so far for the issue?

Comment: JsonPath jsonPathValue = response.jsonPath();                                
String longitudeVal = jsonPathValue.getString("data.longitude");               
System.out.println("the value of Longitude is: "+ longitudeVal);                        
Assert.assertEquals(longitudeVal,eLongitude);                                 @SiddarthSreeni Need to assert value from Json response and excel value read. Assert the value from excel and Json Response , if matches then test cases will pass otherwise will fail.

Comment: Apache POI can be used to read excel value, then do an assertEquals